# finding the probability of catching certain colours of fish

Tags: probability

Consider a population of fish (of the same species) that have different colour patterns. $45\%$ of the fish are green, $15\%$ of the fish are yellow, and $40\%$ of the fish are blue. The coloration patterns are independent of each other.

a.  What is the probability that you CATCH 2 YELLOW FISH?

$P(2~\text{Yellow}) = (0.15) \cdot (0.15) = 0.023\%$

b.  What is the probability you catch 3 BLUE FISH or 3 YELLOW FISH or 3 GREEN FISH?

$P(3B~\text{or}~3Y~\text{or}~3G) = 3(0.40) + 3(0.15) + 3(0.45) = 3\%$

c.  What is the probability of catching 2 BLUE FISH and 1 GREEN FISH?

$P(2B~\text{and}~1G) = 2(0.40) \cdot 1(0.45) = 0.36\%$

Comment: Welcome to MSE :) Do you have any thoughts on the problems? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You seem to be missing a very crucial part of the problem.  What are we doing with these fish?  Just looking at them and going "ooh" and "aah" over their colors?  The probability we catch any fish at all is zero because we are being kind to them and letting them swim freely.  If you want us to catch three fish, then you have to say we are.  If we are catching some other number of fish, then tell us how many.

Comment: You edited., good, that means you are paying at least some attention to the comments.  Your edit however does not address the issue of clarifying.  For (a) for instance, is this "What is the probability **that if when catching two fish** that both fish are yellow"  Do you see why this answer is different than the related question "What is the probability **that if when catching three fish** that two of the fish are yellow"

Comment: I'm justing asking the questions that are related to my school work. I don't need to add more details to the question that isn't there. The question asks "what if you catch 2 yellow fish considering the population of the yellow fish is 15%". There's no order in catching the fish.

Comment: Do you recognize that the probability that when drawing a single card from a deck the probability that you picked up the ace of spades if $\frac{1}{52}$, meanwhile the probability when drawing all fifty two cards from a deck of cards that the probability of picking up the ace of spades (among other cards) is $1$?  Do you recognize that these are two very different questions?  Do you recognize that the two questions in my previous comment are also different questions with different answers?

Comment: If that is what the question asks then you should write *that*.

Comment: Well, obviously I didn't write the question. It seemed obvious to me. I guess not to everyone. Please comment on the answers to the questions and comment if they seem correct to you or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before continuing, I really must stress again the importance of correctly phrased questions.  The probability that I draw an ace of spades from a fair deck of playing cards when drawing a single card is $\frac{1}{52}$.  The probability that I draw an ace of spades from a fair deck of playing cards when I pick the entire deck up into my hands is $1$.  The probability that I draw an ace of spades from a fair deck of playing cards on a typical day, noting that most days I don't have any reason to even look at, much less pick up, any playing cards is going to be closer to zero.

When asking questions about probabilities, the *experiment* being discussed must be clearly and unambiguously outlined as depending on how the experiment is conducted the results can and will change.

In your problem it is implied, but not made clear, that we are catching fish of various colors at various rates and the result of each individual catch is independent of one another.  It is also implied but not made clear that we are catching multiple fish in sequence.  The quantity of fish that we catch however is left entirely ambiguous.

It is implied that in the second and third problem we are catching exactly three fish in total.  Does that imply that in the first problem we are also catching exactly three fish?  Or does the fact that the only number mentioned in the first problem being $2$ imply that we are catching only two fish?  Why should in the same hypothetical scenario we be catching different numbers of fish in total?  Does that imply then that in our hypothetical experiment both catching two fish and catching three fish are possibilities and so we should account for that in our calculations?  With what frequency do we catch two fish?  With what frequency do we catch three fish?  You have not made it clear and both problems are not only valid, but also common introductory probability questions.

If we were fishing in reality, it would not be guaranteed that we catch exactly two fish, so the probability of having caught two yellow fish is not only contingent upon the colors of the caught fish as both being yellow, but also contingent on the outcome that it was *two fish* that were caught in the first place instead of some other number of fish.

---

(a)

The probability that when drawing *two* fish that both fish are yellow is $0.15 \times 0.15=0.0225 = 2.25\%$ (*not .0225% which would have been .000225*)

The probability that when drawing *three* fish that exactly two of the fish are yellow is $\binom{3}{2}0.15^2(1-0.15)^{3-2}$, or in general when drawing $n$ fish that exactly two of them are yellow is $\binom{n}{2}0.15^2(1-0.15)^{n-2}$

Recall that for independent events $A$ and $B$ the probability of both occurring is $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$

---

(b)

The probability that when drawing *three* fish, that all three are blue, or all three are yellow, or all three are green will be:

$$0.45^3 + 0.15^3+0.4^3=0.1585$$

> Side note: $3\times 0.45 + 3\times 0.15 + 3\times 0.4 = 3.00 = 300\%$ is not a possible probability.  Probabilities are always between $0$ and $1$.  Multiplying by a factor of $3$ was incorrect here.  If we wanted the first, second, and third fish to be blue that would be $0.4\times 0.4\times 0.4=0.4^3$, not $0.4+0.4+0.4=3\times 0.4$.  Similarly for the others.

---

(c)

the probability that when drawing *three* fish, that two of the fish are blue and one is green would be:

$$0.40^2\times 0.45\times \binom{3}{2}$$

and more generally, when drawing $n$ fish, that $b$ of them are blue, $g$ of them are green, and $y$ of them are yellow where $n=b+g+y$ would be:

$$\frac{n!}{b!g!y!}\times 0.4^b\times 0.45^g\times 0.15^y$$

This is the multinomial distribution.

> Your attempted answer of $2\times 0.4\times 0.45$ made the same mistake as before, multiplying by the number of times the color occurred rather than using that as an exponent.  Correcting that to be $0.4^2\times 0.45$ is still incorrect as that is the probability of very specifically drawing the fish one at a time and very specifically the first fish being blue, the second fish also being blue, and the third fish being green, but the order in which the fish occurred could have been different.